# Плавная смена фона кнопки с градиентного на прозрачный

Tags: css, css3, html5, css-animation

У меня есть кнопка с линейно-градиентным фоном, оранжевой рамкой и текстом.

При наведении курсора на кнопку я хочу, чтобы фон стал прозрачным, не меняя другие свойства кнопки.
Я пытался перевести непрозрачность на ноль, но, очевидно, это скроет границу и текст.

Я также попытался перенести `background`, но это не работает, потому что у меня нет конечной точки для `transition`, так как фон должен быть прозрачным.

```css
body {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red,yellow);
    border: solid orange 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

<sub>CSS button transition linear-gradient background into transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54855781/7394871) от участника  [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7944637/nick).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54855781/7394871

Comment: Как то по-другому название надо перевести, наверное

Comment: @Stranger in the Q перевод заголовка как есть в оригинале. Может ты хочешь придать заголовку другую смысловую нагрузку? Предлагай варианты

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, перевод заголовка - как название товара на aliexpress))

Comment: @Qwertiy♦  критиковать каждый может :))) Я просил варианты предложить

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, "Плавная смена фона кнопки с градиентного на прозрачный" - годится?

Comment: Как плавно изменить фон кнопки с линейного градиента на прозрачный, что то в этом духе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данный момент это решение поддерживается только Хромом с включенными Experimental Web Platform features ([а именно](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5640265926705152)):

```js
CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--alpha', 
  syntax: '<number>', 
  initialValue: 1, 
  inherits: true,
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  --alpha: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,var(--alpha)), rgba(255,255,0,var(--alpha))) transparent;
  border: solid orange 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: --alpha 1s linear;
}

.button:hover {
  --alpha: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

> [image: скриншот настроек хрома]
>
> [image: скринвидео]

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ну ладно, нахимичил)) Правда, надо ещё дождаться, когда браузеры начнут это без флагов есть... А пока наслаждаемся exception'ом в консоли и гифкой :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90573/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-alexandr-tt).

Answer (score 6):

При использовании псевдоэлемента для фона, вы можете легко сделать это:

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  border: solid orange 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:0;
  background:transparent;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  transition:1s;
}
.button:hover::before {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

Вот еще одна идея без использования псевдоэлемента, где вы можете использовать изменение `background-color` и `background-size`.

Хитрость заключается в том, чтобы сохранить один из цветов градиента прозрачным, чтобы мы могли видеть `background-color` (у вас может быть `transition` на прозрачный).

Затем вы увеличиваете `background-size`, чтобы скрыть нижний цвет, и мы видим только прозрачный.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  border: solid orange 2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, yellow);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition:1s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color:transparent;
  background-size:100% 500%;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

Или подумайте о корректировке размера фона, чтобы иметь другой вид `transition`:

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  border: solid orange 2px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red, yellow),
    transparent;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:left; /*change this to change the way the transtion happen*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition:1s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-size:0% 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [CSS button transition linear-gradient background into transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856116/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал с помощью JavaScript и переменных CSS.

```js
const b = document.querySelector(".button");

b.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
  let i = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
  if(i>0){
    i=i - 0.009;
    b.style.setProperty("--a", i);
    b.style.setProperty("--b", i); 
  }
  },5);
});

b.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
  let i = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
  if(i<1){
    i=i + 0.009;
    b.style.setProperty("--a", i);
    b.style.setProperty("--b", i);   
  }
  },5);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
    --a:1;
    --b:1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,var(--a)),rgba(255,255,0,var(--b)));
    background-color:transparent;
    border: solid orange 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [CSS button transition linear-gradient background into transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856075/7394871)
 от участника  [@dgknca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10698741/dgknca).</sub>

Comment: Что-то тут `clearInterval` не хватает. И зачем тебе 2 одинаковых переменных?